# What happens when MSSQLServer sink looses SQL server connection?

Tags: serilog-sinks-mssqlserver

What happens when Serilog MSSQLServer Sink looses SQL server connection?

I would like to know how the sink reacts, when it looses connection to the SQL server, because the server is out of service like monthly maintenance.

Will the sink recover?
Will it loose logs?
Will it try to write logs not stored in the database, while the SQL Server was out of service?

I haven't find answers here on StackOverflow or in the sinks forum on Github.